# Can I Install Windows using PowerISO?

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10, and I want to update to the new "Redstone 2 1703"; would it work if I mount the "Redstone 2 1703" image using PowerISO, and install from there?

Comment: Sure; But you should use the native ability to mount ISOs instead

Comment: what do you mean by "native" ability?

Comment: The ability to mount an ISO is a native built-in feature of Windows 8, 8.1, and 10.  In other words Power ISO is a useless program if your running Windows 10

Comment: Oh OK, will try that now.